# ASP.NET Core, Ajax call for Delete does not reload div content in Index page(PartialView) from html json response

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have defined some simple code in my Index.chtml to list all collection have been made so far.

```
@model IEnumerable<PaymentTracking.Models.PaymentCollection>
<div id="view-all">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ViewAll", Model)
</div>
```

_ViewAll.chtml

```
@model IEnumerable<PaymentTracking.Models.PaymentCollection>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AirlineCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PaymentCollectionAmount)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PaymentCollectionForDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PaymentCollectionRemarks)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedUser)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedDt)
            </th>
            <th> 
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AirlineCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentCollectionAmount)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentCollectionForDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentCollectionRemarks)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedUser)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDt)
                </td>
                <td>
                        <a class='btn btn-danger text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;' onclick="Delete('/PaymentCollection/Delete?id=@item.PaymentCollectionID')"> Delete </a>


                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript handle Delete Action

```
function Delete(url) {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true
    }).then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) { 
                        $("#view-all").html(data.html);
                        toastr.success(data.message);    
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Action Method of my controller

```
        [HttpDelete]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            var pcolFromDb = await _db.PaymentCollections.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.PaymentCollectionID == id);
            if (pcolFromDb == null)
            {
return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error while Deleting", isValue = false, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "Upsert", PaymentCollection) });
            }
            _db.PaymentCollections.Remove(pcolFromDb);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();



return Json(new { success = true, message = "Delete successful", isValid = true, html = "successful"});
        }
```

I got the response and saw toastr message of success after deleted but the content of `<div id="view-all">` does not reload with html content return from Ajax called.

Below is the screenshot of what return after Delete button called

[image]

Would you mind pointing out which points I have done wrong?

Comment: According to your description, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well. I suggest you could try to return a success message in the `return Json(new { success = true, message = "Delete successful", isValid = true, html = "Success");`.  If this has changed, I suggest you could post the related codes which is related with `Helper.RenderRazorViewToString`.

Comment: Try adding `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax()` call config. I'm not sure if the `JsonResult` adds the required headers so you can force jQuery to interpret the response as JSON

Comment: I have added dataType: 'json' and also updated in Controler for return Json(new { success = true, message = "Delete successful", isValid = true, html = "successfull"  }); but still content of div in index does not refresh.

Comment: Could you please also update the code in your question. Have you confirmed that the code in `if (data.success) { ... }` actually runs? The only other thing I can think of is that you have multiple elements with `id="view-all"`. jQuery's ID selector only picks the first one and you shouldn't have duplicate IDs anyway

Comment: I have updated the code in the question. The code in if (data.success) {...} is running because I have seen toastr message "Delete successful" appear at the top right of the page, only the content of the div does not reload

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about caches, after clear all caches everything working as expected on initial code post in the question.

Thanks you for points me out a good ways to debug.